# OpenCV & Python: Cover a colored mask over a image

Tags: python, opencv, mask, roi

I want to cover a image with a transparent solid color overlay in the shape of a black-white mask

Currently I'm using the following java code to implement this.

```
redImg = new Mat(image.size(), image.type(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
redImg.copyTo(image, mask);
```

I'm not familiar with the python api.

So I want to know if there any alternative api in python.
Is there any better implementation?

image:

[image: src img]

mask:

[image: mask]

what i want:

[image: what i want]

Comment: Ok, Can you also show what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Have you tried some permutations of blending the two images? :)

Answer (score 24):

Now after I deal with all this Python, OpenCV, Numpy thing for a while, I find out it's quite simple to implement this with code:

```
image[mask] = (0, 0, 255)
```

-------------- the original answer --------------

I solved this by the following code:

```
redImg = np.zeros(image.shape, image.dtype)
redImg[:,:] = (0, 0, 255)
redMask = cv2.bitwise_and(redImg, redImg, mask=mask)
cv2.addWeighted(redMask, 1, image, 1, 0, image)
```

Comment: Regarding your updated answer, I think you still need `addWeighted` otherwise you won't overlay with transparency.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to convert the mask to a binary format where pixels are either `0` (black) or `255` (white). White pixels represent sections that are kept while black sections are thrown away. Then set all white pixels on the mask to your desired `BGR` color.

**Input image and mask**

[image]
[image]

**Result**

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.jpg', 0)
mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
image[mask==255] = (36,255,12)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me:

```
red = np.ones(mask.shape)
red = red*255
img[:,:,0][mask>0] = red[mask>0]
```

so I made a 2d array with solid 255 values and replaced it with my image's red band in pixels where the mask is not zero.
[redmask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYbMV.png)